# How to replace strings in the last n-lines of multiple files in linux

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can I replace strings in lets say 'last 10 lines' of multiple files?

I have about 100 files with the same extension '.txt' and I would like to replace string 'GLN' to 'LOO' in the last 10 lines of each file. How do I do this? I know how to do it for one file but not for several files.
When I use this command ;

```
for i in `head -3 *.txt  | awk '{print $4}'`
     do
                   sed -i 's/GLN/LOO/g' *.txt 
     done
```

It replaces GLN everywhere it appears in the files and not just the last 10 lines. Please, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what `head -3 *.txt  | awk '{print $4}'` returns here since you haven't shown us a sample of your file(s), however `sed -i 's/GLN/LOO/g' *.txt` will replace **all of** the instances of GLN in **all** the lines in **all** the files matching `*.txt`, provided the loop executes at least once.

AFAIK there's no direct way to address the last *n* lines of a file in sed - so to use that, you would need to calculate the offset externally, using `wc -l` and shell arithmetic for example:

```
for f in *.txt; do 
  start=$(( $(wc -l <"$f") - 9 ))
  sed "$start"',$s/GLN/LOO/g' "$f"
done
```

(I removed the `-i` so output goes to the terminal, for testing). You could use something like `awk 'END{print NR-9}' "$f"` in place of `$(( $(wc -l <"$f") - 9 ))` to get the start offset if your intention was to use awk.

Alternatively you could use `tac` to invert the file and make replacements in the first *n* lines, then `tac` the result - although that makes in-place replacement complicated.

In this situation I would probably reach for `ed` or `ex` which do support numerical address offsets ex. testing with output to the terminal:

```
for f in *.txt; do 
  printf '%s\n' '$-9,$s/GLN/LOO/g' ',p' | ed -s "$f"
done
```

Once you are happy that it's doing the right thing, change `,p` to `wq` to **w**rite the result to the file (equivalent of sed's `-i`).

Answer (score 1):

I would use tac and awk functions for this job as follows:

```
tac file1.txt | awk 'NR<11 {gsub("GLN","LOO")};{print}' | tac
```